# How to get Aws credentials for elastc search?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to use AWS Elasticsearch services.On localhost, I installed elastic search locally which is working perfectly. But, now I want to use AWS elastic search but for that I need credentials like

```
        'aws'             => env('AWS_ELASTICSEARCH_ENABLED', false),
        'aws_region'      => env('AWS_REGION', ''),
        'aws_key'         => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', ''),
        'aws_secret'      => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '')
        'aws_credentials' => $credentials
```

I don't know from where I can get that information. Please help me to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bilal, on creating index in AES, you get an endpoint. Simply use that endpoint in your application and send cURL/ CLI request to your index.

Note, in your Access Policy of AES, allow your IP to access AES endpoint.

[image]

Comment: if i need to give access to my localhost:8000 then what i need to do?

Comment: You can allow your own IP in Access policy. Check your IP from https://whatismyipaddress.com/ ...and add that address to Access Policy. So, whenever request made from your internet, you will get response.

Comment: i am getting this error ` Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException No alive nodes found in your cluster`

Comment: read this. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230626 , also please verify, are you able to query index through Kibana?

Comment: thanks i have to add `:443` at the end of endpoint

Answer (score 0):

How to get your AWS credentials is explained in:

- [Understanding and getting your AWS credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html)

Further, you can also setup a local AWS profile on your computer as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html).